# What is the norm of elements of $k_b^*$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, definition

On page 19 of Serre's arithmetic he mentions the group $Nk_B^*$ of norms of elements of $k_b^*$ where $k_b = k(\sqrt{b})$. Here $k = \mathbb{Q}_p$ for $p$ prime or $\infty$. What is the norm and how is this group defined? Unforunately, Serre does not define this term.

Comment: The norm $N$ of an element $x + y \sqrt{b}$ (for $x, y \in \mathbb{Q}_p$) is defined to be $$(x - y\sqrt{b})(x+y\sqrt{b})$$ $Nk_B^{\ast}$ is the image of $k_B^{\ast}$ under the norm map.  It is a group with respect to multiplication, because $N(ac) = N(a)N(c)$ for any $a, c \in k_B$.

Comment: More generally, the norm $N_{L/K}: L \rightarrow K$ is a function defined for any finite separable extension of fields $K \subseteq L$ by $$N_{L/K}(a) = \prod\limits_{\sigma} \sigma(a)$$ where $\sigma$ runs through the $K$-embeddings of $L$ into a fixed algebraically closed field containing $K$ (see any book on field/Galois theory).

Comment: @D_S thank you very much!